# Extra charcters after sorting multidimensional JSON array using JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sorting

I am trying to sort a multidimensional JSON array (called jsontest here) using JQuery using this code:

```
jQuery.fn.sort = function() {  
                    return this.pushStack( [].sort.apply( this, arguments ), []);  
                     };  

function sortLastName(a,b){  
                             if (a.arrtime1 == b.arrtime1){
                                                      return 0;
                                                      }
                             return a.arrtime1 > b.arrtime1 ? 1 : -1;  
                              };  
function sortLastNameDesc(a,b){  
                               return sortLastName(a,b) * -1;  
                                };


x1=$(jsontest).sort(sortLastNameDesc);
```

original jsontest if alerted using javascript is : `[{f_name:"john", arrtime1:"10", sequence:"0", title:"president", url:"google.com", color:"333333"}, {f_name:"michael", arrtime1:"11", sequence:"0", title:"general manager", url:"google.com", color:"333333"}]`

But after sorting: it becomes(x1 is):

`({0:#1={f_name:"michael", arrtime1:"11", sequence:"0", title:"general manager", url:"google.com", color:"333333"}, 1:#2={f_name:"john", arrtime1:"10", sequence:"0", title:"president", url:"google.com", color:"333333"}, length:2, prevObject:{0:#1#, 1:#2#, length:2}, context:(void 0), selector:".(undefined)"})`

Why these extra charcters at the beginning and end? Is there some problem with my sorting function. I am using JQuery 1.6 undefined)"})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using a jQuery functions to do this when you can do it with normal array sort.

```
var foo = jsontest.sort(sortLastNameDesc);
```

All of that "extra" stuff is the fact it is now a jQuery object and not an array.